# Razor Page asp-page tag helper not directing to different folder correctly

Tags: asp.net, razor-pages, asp.net-core-tag-helpers, asp.net-core-5.0

I am working in ASP.NET Core 5 on an MVC application with Razor pages. I am trying to link from a page in one folder to a page in another folder.

From a page in the same folder as the target page, this link works as expected:

```
<a asp-page="Details" asp-route-userid="@member.UserId">@member.FullName</a>
```

It generates the following route from the root:

```
/User/Details/{userId here}
```

From the page I am now trying to link from, in a separate folder, this link does not work as expected:

```
<a asp-page="/User/Details" asp-route-userid="@member.UserId">@member.FullName</a>
```

Instead, this code generates the following route from the root:

```
/?page=%2FUser%2FDetails
```

How can I get the link from a different folder to work properly?

Comment: Strangely, another link from a different file in the same folder (Leaderboard) as the link that is not working uses the exact same code, and works properly: `<a asp-page="/User/Details" asp-route-userId="@member.UserId">@member.FirstName @member.LastName</a>` results in the proper route

Comment: The problem cannot be reproduced based on this information, which may be caused by development environment problems or other coding. If possible, please share the key code of other parts of the page. Besides, you could try to run on other browsers to see if this problem occurs.